# "The file “command.cgi” couldn’t be opened."

Tags: ios, swift, flashair

FlashAir W-04 Fourth Generation SD memory card

In my iOS app directory listing api not working.

Response :

Task .<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])

2019-05-21 23:32:40.267572+0530 Razzo[10489:87069] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1003

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “command.cgi” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=http://flashair/command.cgi?op=100&DIR=/DCIM}

Please help me what was wrong

below code snippet

```
private func getdata() {
        let url100 = URL(string: "http://flashair/command.cgi?op=100&DIR=/DCIM")
        var dirStr: String? = nil
        do {
            if let url100 = url100 {
                dirStr = try String(contentsOf: url100, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
                if let dir = dirStr {
                    arrayfiles = dir.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                }
                tblContent.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
            self.displayAlert(message: error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```

Config file below

[Vendor]

CIPATH=/DCIM/100__TSB/FA000001.JPG

APPMODE=4

APPNETWORKKEY=12345678

VERSION=F15DBW3BW4.00.03

CID=02544d535733324755e3c6dc7b012301

PRODUCT=FlashAir

VENDOR=TOSHIBA

MASTERCODE=f437b71e0e4f

LOCK=1

Answer (score -1):

`contentsOf: url100` would be for a local file URL. You are not providing a valid file URL.

If your file is  remote you need to download the file as data with URLSession. If it is local you need to work out its file URL.

Comment: If you want to use http then add App Transport Security (ATS) in Info.plist

Comment: For reference link for flashair api : https://www.flashair-developers.com/en/documents/api/commandcgi/